CSS and <nav> : prevent country (flag) icon insertion from padding
I'm maintaining a very simple, static webpage which displays my resume. I want to implement a language switcher in the <nav> element so visitors can select either of two languages. This slightly disturbs the otherwise centered text.
style.css
nav { position: sticky; top:0 }
#lang_nav { float: right; margin-right: 5px }
nav, footer { padding:0; text-align: center }

index.html
<nav>
        <a href="/">home</a>
        <a href="index.fr.html" hreflang="fr"
            id="lang_nav" class="lang_fr">
            <img src="media/fr.png" alt="fr">
        </a>
</nav>

I am quite confident there should be a basic CSS property or simple hack to fix the issue. Am I wrong ?

nav { position: sticky; top:0 ;display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;}
#lang_nav { float: right; margin-right: 5px }
nav, footer { padding:0; text-align: center }

<nav >
        <a href="/"></a>
        <a href="/">home</a>
        <a href="index.fr.html" hreflang="fr".  
            id="lang_nav" class="lang_fr">
            <img src="media/fr.png" alt="fr">
        </a>
</nav>


Thanks for the hints but alas overall it's worse. My "home" link, that which I am looking to perfectly center, is then aligned to the very left inside the nav block. Apparently an effect of the display: flex parameter.
